# TypeError: res.status is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm making a function that permits me to upload a picture to imgur in my express API (nodejs),
I'm encountering an error when calling a function returning a promise:

> TypeError: res.status is not a function
> at uploadpicture.then

This is my code:
Where error is raised:

```
  router.post('/upload', (req, res, next)=> { 
    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        if(fieldname == 'image') {
            // the buffer
            file.fileRead = [];
            file.on('data', function(data) {
                // add to the buffer as data comes in
                this.fileRead.push(data);
            });

            file.on('end', function() {
                // create a new stream with our buffered data
                var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat(this.fileRead);
                upload = uploadpicture(finalBuffer).then((res)=>{ //success request
                  console.log(res);
                  res.status(200).json({success: true, message: "Successfully uploaded !", url: res.data.link});
                },(err)=>{ //error
                  res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "Error happenned while uploading !"});
                }).catch((error)=>{
                  console.log(error);
                  res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "Error happenned while uploading !"});
                });

            })
        }
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        //busboy finished
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

And the function :

```
function uploadpicture(stream){ //get picture stream
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    var options = {
      uri: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          //'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + config.client_id_imgur // put client id here
      },
      formData: {
          image: stream,
          type: 'file'
      },
      auth: {
        bearer: config.access_token_imgur,
      }
  };
  
  request(options)
      .then((parsedBody)=> {
          resolve(parsedBody);
      })
      .catch((err)=> {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err.toString())
      });
    });
  }
```

The code works perfectly, but I don't know why suddenly this error happened,
I tried to:

**change arrow functions to `function(){}`**
**Add next to the route parameters**

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The accepted answer directly addresses the OP's problem, but I post another solution since you can also encounter this error in other places.

When you have:

```
api.use((error: ErrorRequestHandler, request: ExpressRequest, response: ExpressResponse) => {
  response.status(500).end() // response.status is not a function
})
```

Because the error handling route *must* accept 4 arguments for express to identify it as an error middleware.

```
api.use((error: ErrorRequestHandler, request: ExpressRequest, response: ExpressResponse, next: NextFunction) => {
  response.status(500).end()
})
```

Just adding the next function (or whatever argument you're missing) will fix it.

https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/416#issuecomment-514508137

Comment: Very well remembered, although the issue is not about middlewares but it could have a similar issue

Comment: So this error occurs if your code is from the times that `app.use` accepted 3 parameters instead of 4?

Comment: [close](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) to the docs of `app.use`, scroll further down to the `error-handling`..

Answer (score 18):

At this point:

```js
upload = uploadpicture(finalBuffer).then((res)=>{ //success request
```

the `res`is the result of promise `uploadpicture` function (that is the `parsedBody`), not the `res` from the express route. So indeed, it has no `status` function. Try change the `then` callback name like:

```js
upload = uploadpicture(finalBuffer).then((otherName)=>{ //success request
```

Comment: Is `res` a reserved word? I do not get your point. If I use `othername` it has a `status` function?

Comment: actually is not a reserved word. The point is `res` is the name of the response variable from express route. When he named the `promise.then` response as `res`, the .then scope assumes the `res` is from resolved promise, not from express route. And indeed it has no `.status` function. Renaming the promise.then `res` solves the issue, since we usually call `res` the object from express route. If you prefer to rename the express route object to e.g. otherNameElse, then you would need to call `otherNameElse.status` function to respond into the route.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error:

> TypeError: res.status is not a function

Because the order should be `(err, req, res, next)` not `(req, res, err, next)`,
example below

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
    res.status(statusCode)
    res.json({
        message : err.message,
        stack :process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack, 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the async/await method:

```
const notifications = await notifications.aggregate({...})
if(notifications){
  return res.status(200).json({ data: notifications })
}else{
  return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No notifications found'})
}
```

**Make sure that you are including your return statements.** Not including a return statement will cause this. Something else that I was doing is I had `JSON` instead of `json`, which will most definitely throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by change the order of functions (req,next,res)  to (req,res,next). May it needs them in a strict order to call them properly!

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is

> Error-handling middleware always takes four arguments. You must
> provide four arguments to identify it as an error-handling middleware
> function. Even if you don’t need to use the next object, you must
> specify it to maintain the signature. Otherwise, the next object will
> be interpreted as regular middleware and will fail to handle errors.

In my case, I had enabled ES-Lint and it warned me about unused `next` so I removed it... Later on in the production logs started seeing this error. so do not forget to add this to lint ignore list.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing:

the order of (req,res,next) really matters.

In my case the problem was just the order. For example if I want to get user info:

```
export const getUserInfo = async(res:Response,req:Request,next:NextFunction) => {
try {
    const userId = await req.user 
    const user = await userModel.findById(userId);

res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    user,
})


} catch (error:any) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message,400))
}
```

here I used:

1. **req** first
2. Then I used **res**

Which was the problem. after switching them on function parameters everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was setting the type of `req` and `res` to `Request` and `Response`, respectively, without actually importing these types from Express!

Answer (score -2):

Order of parameters really matters i had error in below code

```js
const getImagesByBrand = async (res) => {
  try {
    const images = await Image.find();
    res.status(200).json(images);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

I was not giving req as parameter and that was the reason for error i just add req,res and it worked