# From pages to app (NextJS): rest.status is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am trying to update from Next 13.2.5 to 14.1.0 and use `app/api/example/route.js` instead of `pages/api/example.js`.

I get the error `TypeError: res.status is not a function at POST` in the code below.

My older version of `pages/api/example.js` is exactly the same but without `POST`, so I used `export async function(req, res)` and it works fine. But tried different aspects in the updated version (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584314/typeerror-res-status-is-not-a-function)) but I cannot figure out and I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export async function POST(req, res) {
  if (!configuration.apiKey) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: {
        message: "OpenAI API key not configured",
      },
    });
    return;
  }

  const { messages } = req.body;

  if (!Array.isArray(messages)) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: {
        message: "Invalid conversation format",
      },
    });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const incomingMessages = req.body.messages || [];

    const messages = [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: `This is a roleplay. You are a participant in a market research study, simulating a 
        potential customer's perspective on a new product.
        `,
      },

      ...incomingMessages,
    ];

    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: messages,
      temperature: 0,
      max_tokens: 1000,
    });

    const responseMessage = completion.data.choices[0].message;
    const updatedConversationHistory = [...messages, responseMessage];

    res.status(200).json({ messages: updatedConversationHistory });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.status, error.response.data);
      res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.error(`Error with OpenAI API request: ${error.message}`);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: {
          message: "An error occurred during your request.",
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, route handlers only receive the request as parameter. You have to return a response using either [`Response`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#extended-nextrequest-and-nextresponse-apis) or [`NextResponse`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response), like so:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// ...

export async function POST(req) {
  if (!configuration.apiKey) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: { message: "OpenAI API key not configured" } },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```